# XAMPP with PostgreSQL 9

Tags: php, windows, apache, postgresql, xampp

I installed XAMPP 1.7.4(VC6) from this link:
http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-win32-1.7.4-VC6-installer.exe

The XAMPP 1.7.4 contains:

- Apache 2.2.17,
- MySQL 5.5.8,
- PHP 5.3.5

Then, I installed PostgreSQL 9 (64bit).

It's very simple to enable PHP and PostgreSQL connection - just uncomment `extension=php_pgsql.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` in the `php.ini` file.

But, I got an error when starting Apache:

[image]
[image]

Can anybody help and explain?

Answer (score 3):

May be you can fix it with follow this [instructions](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/pgAgent-installation-fails-LIBPQ-DLL-is-missing-PostgreSQL-9-0-2-x64-2008-Windows-Server-x64-td3351434.html).

Comment: from your link mention on 64 bit version lib can work with 32 bit, Thanks. may be i should install bitmani :D

Comment: erf sorry... yeah it's may be a good way to do what you want. AAnother way was to create a virtual machine with virtual box and set the exact environment you need and so no .dll problem :p

Answer (score 3):

If the above doesn't work, try copying the libpg.dll file from your PostgreSQL installation folder over to your apache/bin folder

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I just copied the lib*.dll files from pgsql/lib/ directory to the apache /bin directory. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply navigate to your `Postgresql/psqlODBC/0900/bin` and copy all contents here to your xampp apache/bin directory, then restart Apache. This worked on my xampp 1.7.4.